# ElementNotVisibleException Error with xpath selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Hi I am **scraping** a website and I am using selenium python. The code is as below

```
url ='https://www.hkexnews.hk/'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)

tier1 = browser.find_element_by_id('tier1-select')
tier1.click()

tier12 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-value="rbAfter2006"]')
tier12.click()
    
time.sleep(1)
    
tier2 = browser.find_element_by_id('rbAfter2006')
tier2.click()
    
tier22 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='rbAfter2006']//*[@class='droplist-item droplist-item-level-1']//*[text()='Circulars']")
tier22.click()

tier23 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='rbAfter2006']//*[@class='droplist-item droplist-item-level-2']//*[text()='Securities/Share Capital']")
tier23.click()

tier24 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='rbAfter2006']//*[@class='droplist-group droplist-submenu level3']//*[text()='Issue of Shares']")
tier24.click()
```

It works stops at tier23 by showing ElementNoVisibleException. I have tried with different class, yet it seems like not working. Thank you for you help

Comment: Which is **tier23** exactly?

Comment: tier23 is the the submenu under Circulars
The button flow is Circulars -> Securities/Share Capital -> Issue of Shares

Answer (score 2):

There are two elements that can be selected by your XPath. The first one is hidden. Try below to select required element:

```
tier23 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='rbAfter2006']//li[@aria-expanded='true']//*[@class='droplist-item droplist-item-level-2']//*[text()='Securities/Share Capital']")
```

or shorter

```
tier23 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@aria-expanded='true']//a[.='Securities/Share Capital']")
tier23.location_once_scrolled_into_view
tier23.click()
```

P.S. Note that that option will still be not visible because you need to scroll list down first. I used  `tier23.location_once_scrolled_into_view` for this purpose

Also it's better to use Selenium built-in [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) instead of `time.sleep`